# One function for two $.ajax success

Tags: jquery

I want to use One function to send data to the server.

For example, The user clicks a checkbox for the email address to send a document via email and onclick on "send email" button it calls the sendemailfax() function. But, if you want to fax a document a popup appears for user to select fax number and onclick the "send fax" button it also calls the sendemailfax() function.

```
 function sendemailfax(url)
{
    $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : "sendDoc.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : { emailAddresses: emails, faxNumbers: getFaxNumbers(), url: url, lname: lname,   fname: fname }, // Data to be sent
    success: function(data){
       if( data.success )
        {
            alert("Email/Fax sent successfully");
        }
        else
        {
           alert("There was a mistake, try again");
        }
     },

    error: function(req, status, error) {
       console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err);
    }
 });
}
```

what is happening is that if I just want to send the fax I get the error because the email being empty.

I wanted to use one function instead of duplicating code for just getting different success messages or errors.

I don't know how to use the same function call and have separate success depending if is fax or email. Sometimes the email will be empty and sometimes the fax will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Make two javascript functions and call them against your ajax callbacks..

```
function funcSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if( data.success ) {
        alert("Email/Fax sent successfully");
    } else {
        alert("There was a mistake, try again");
    }
}

function funcError( req, status, error ) {
    console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err);
}
```

And in your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : "sendDoc.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : { 
        emailAddresses: emails, 
        faxNumbers: getFaxNumbers(), 
        url: url, 
        lname: lname,   
        fname: fname 
    }, // Data to be sent

    // here are the two functions
    success: funcSuccess, 
    error: funcError 
});
```

Comment: For some reason still getting a popup for the email. I'm checking the server json_encode message

Answer (score 0):

Make two separate ajax request for mail and fax.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : "sendDoc.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : { 
                 emailAddresses: emails, 
                 url: url, 
                 lname: lname,   
                 fname: fname 
    }, // Data to be sent
    success: EmailSuccess,
    error: EmailError
});
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : "sendDoc.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : { 
                 faxNumbers: getFaxNumbers(), 
                 url: url, 
                 lname: lname,   
                 fname: fname 
    }, // Data to be sent
    success: faxSuccess,
    error: faxError
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function sendemailfax(url,paramData,successCallback,failureCallback)
{
    $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : "sendDoc.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : paramData, // Data to be sent
    success: function(data){
       if($.isFunction(successCallback)){successCallback(data);}
     },

    error: function(req, status, error) {
       if($.isFunction(failureCallback)){failureCallback(req, status, error);}
    }
 });
}
```

HOW TO USE

```
    function postData("sendDoc.php",{ emailAddresses: emails, faxNumbers: getFaxNumbers(), url: url, lname: lname,   fname: fname },
    function(data){
     //on success
},function(req, status, error){
     //on error   
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to initialize the value out side of the ajax call.

2.Use  if condition to check whether the email value or the fax value is empty or not.

```
    function sendemailfax(url)
             {
                var fax_no=getFaxNumbers();//initialize the fax number here*
           if(emails=="")
              { 
                emails=0;
              }

           if(fax_no=="")
              {
                fax_no=0;
              }
           else{

               $.ajax({
               type    : 'POST',
               url     : "sendDoc.php",
               dataType: 'json',
               data    : { emailAddresses: emails, faxNumbers: fax_no,
                           url: url, lname: lname,   fname: fname }, // Data to be sent

               success : function(data){

                        if( data.success )
                           {
                               alert("Email/Fax sent successfully");
                           }

                        else
                           {
                                alert("There was a mistake, try again");
                           }
                       },

              error: function(req, status, error) {
                              console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err);
                       }
        });
} }
```